# What is the best way to update Erlang on a Windows installation with RabbitMQ

Tags: windows, erlang, rabbitmq

Today I tried to update to the latest version of Erlang on my Windows 10. (19.1 to 19.2)
Finally, I ended up with having to uninstall the current version of Erlang and RabbitMQ, rebooting (for the current version was still loaded in memory), removing the remaining files in 'Program Files' and re-install Erlang and RabbitMQ.

I guess there must be an easier and quicker way, but the documentation did not help me.

Anyone?

Yes, I know: "Use the Linux binaries!", but I have to be able support the Windows distribution too.

Comment: I ended up doing the same thing. Couldn't find any docs on it

Comment: Very linux specifix but this slide deck by Rusty Klophaus who works at Basho gives a great insight how they manage multiple erlang versions - https://www.slideshare.net/rklophaus/winning-the-edit-build-test-cycle

Answer (score 4):

I upgraded Erlang and a single node of RabbitMQ on Windows Server 2012 R2 without having to reboot or do any file clean up.  Taking your experience  into consideration I performed the upgrades in the following steps:

- stop the RabbitMQ service
- uninstall Erlang
- install the new version of Erlang
- perform an in place upgrade of RabbitMQ

I upgraded a single node of Rabbit MQ based on [these instructions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/upgrade.html#single-node-upgrade).